# Are static methods/fields/blocks part of metaspace? Is metaspace apart of heap and is in native memory?

Tags: java

Here in 2021 and lets say Java 13:
Are static methods/fields/blocks part of metaspace? Is metaspace apart of heap and is in native memory?
( I've read many topics here, marked from 2011 since PermGen ages, so I wanna know how is it in 2021 and Java 13)

Comment: What is the underlying question that an answer here would help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static methods and blocks aren't a thing in the same way fields are. Thus, you've asked 2 utterly unrelated questions:

1. Where do methods and other code go, `static` or not?
2. Where do (static) fields go?

### Where do methods and other code go?

Think about it: A method is just a block of code, and it **is** static; even a non-static method is the same actual 'content' for any instance. It's just that in a non-static method, any reference to 'a field' is syntax sugared to `this.x`, and the `this` ref points at a different object.

There is no functional difference between `a` and `b` here:

```
private class Foo {
    int x;

    public void a() {
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }

    public static void b(Foo instance) {
        System.out.println(instance.x);
    }
}
```

So, **all** methods and blocks are in this sense 'static': They exist only once in memory no matter how many instances exist, and regardless of whether a method is static or not.

It would be an utter waste of gigantic amounts of memory if e.g. having a few million instances of `java.lang.String` in memory meant that your computer is holding a few million copies of the `toLowerCase()` method in memory.

So, that's *not* how it works. There'll be only one `toLowerCase()` in memory. Even though that is not a static method.

What's in memory, specifically, is the entire class, as in, the bytecode of it. In addition, more can be in memory: Java has a so-called hotspot compiler, which means that java keeps continuous track of various statistics about a method (how often it is invoked, for example, and even if it is overridable (it is not marked `final`, is not `private`, and is not in a `final` class) but is never actually overridden, as in, no class is loaded that does that - that's all tracked. From time to time the JVM will take a moment and does a fairly intelligent rewrite of a method into optimized machine code, making assumptions based on that bookkeeping. For example, it'll 'hardcode' links to methods that *could* be overridden but never are, but it will then invalidate these optimized machine code blocks if later on these conclusions cease to be true (for example, now you DO use a class that overrides that method).

The point is: The original bytecode must remain as a hotspotted take may become invalid later, but the whole point of hotspotting is to keep the optimized machine-code (the hotspotted code) around for future executions as well, so now there are **2** separate 'takes' on the same method in memory somewhere: The basic bytecode, and the optimized variant of it.

Where all this goes is **not specified**. Who knows where it goes - the java language spec and the JVM spec simply do not state it. Note that the command line options of `java` (the executable) aren't in any spec either. Certainly the `-X` and the `-XX` options aren't specced at all. The idea that there is a hotspotted variant isn't specced either; it's just how just about every JVM implementation out there operates.

So where does it go? You'd have to peruse the manual of your JVM implementor. It's not something that fits within the domain of 'a java question'. However, generally, yes, that is precisely what 'metaspace' / 'permgen' are about.

### Where do static fields go?

On heap. They do not exist in permgen or metaspace. It's just that they are 'associated' with the instance of the `java.lang.Class`, effectively (I'm oversimplifying a tad), instead of any particular instance. That Class is never getting unloaded unless you're using dynamic classloading, and therefore, that variable is never eligible for garbage collection as you'd expect. Nevertheless, the ref exists in heap.

Comment: And metaspace is apart of heap, in native memory and can grow